# Don''t get value from Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 datepicker

Tags: datepicker

I am using Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 datepicker ,try to get maxday and minday value from datepicker,but i am not geting.Please Any one can help me.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the documentation, you can enable/disable dates via the code below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker6" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker6"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker6" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hes not asking to enable/disable dates. He wants to get the selected date value, presumably required for some other part of their code